# Activate a DelegatingHandler from web.config

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to have a DelegatingHandler active only on Production environments? Like add it to the Configuration from web.config instead of adding it on `Application_Start()` as `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(....`?

Comment: No you need to add it to the message handlers but what you can do is create the handler to get a setting from the config file that would indicate if it should perform its designed purpose or just let the request pass through

Comment: Show an example of the handler in question.

Comment: It's the typical DelegatingHandler to enforce HTTPS. I want our development environments to be accessed via HTTP and avoid having Developers to allow the IIS Express certificate and such.

Comment: My ideas was not to add it via code, but, to add it via web.config when seting up production.

Comment: Then as I described you can check that on the handler based on config

Comment: Take a look at this article. http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you need to add it to the message handlers but what you can do is create the handler to get a setting from the config file that would indicate if it should perform its designed purpose or just let the request pass through

Pseudo Code

```cs
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

    bool active = //...get configuration value;

    if(active) {
        //...perform some action
    }

    var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    if(active) {
        //...perform some action
    }

    return response
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution. It just seems weird that given how usually you can activate similar behavior from web.config it's not the case for DelegatingHandlers.

Comment: I ended up implementing it using the #if !DEBUG syntax to add or not the handler at configuration time (before calling `config.MessageHandlers.Add(`)